# Editing WFS with max feature limit in QGis

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

I'm serving a large layer (500 thousand polygons) using Geoserver WFS and what to be able to edit it using QGis. I've set a feature limit on the layer so I wont overload GeoServer with the request.

I can successully load and edit the WFS layer in QGIS but as soon as I reach the WFS feature limit, QGis will not bring any new polygons as I pan through the map canvas, even when I hit the refresh button in QGis. I was under the impression that QGIS would keep on updating the WFS layer whenever I moved around and that the feature limit in GeoServer would be a limit to a single request and not a total request. Am I getting things wrong?

Comment: What version are you using? I had a similar issue that seemed to be resolved in 2.2

Comment: I'm using Qgis 2.2 and geoserver 2.3. I also have the cache feature turned off in QGis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS does not automatically refresh the WFS layer unless feature caching is turned off. The selection box is so far right in the Add WFS layers that is tends to be hidden.

[image]

In a non-cached mode QGIS is sending a new WFS request after every pan or zoom by using the visible map area as a BBOX.

The refresh button did not work for you because in a cached mode WFS requests do not use BBOX. Resfresh brings you the same features again. However, if they were meanwhile edited in the database you would get fresh data.

[image: MaxFeatures hit before BBOX is full]
[image: Small BBOX needs less than 100000 features to be filled]

Comment: If I limit the number of features served in the WFS server, will QGIS work around that as I move the BBox? I mean, say I limit the server to 100 features and on the first load I get 50 features for my BBOX. Then I move and I should get other features displayed (+60). Since that exceeds the 100 feature limit in the server, will I have 10 features missing?

Comment: No, when you move the map a new request is made and the previously fetched features will be wiped out.

Comment: This is not what I'm seeing. I've limited the WFS features in geoserver (2.3) and QGIS (2.2 OsGeo4W) will bring the features in "stripes", from top to bottom. So if I zoom to an area at the top of the region, the features will appear but, when I zoom to an area at the bottom and refresh the layers, no features are shown. This is with and without feature cache.

Comment: I edited the answer and added two screen captures from QGIS 2.0.1. WFS layer is added with Cache feature off. New zoom and pan leads to new GetFeature. One exception, though. Zoom in within a previously fetched area does not trigger a new GetFeature.

Comment: That is not the behavior I'm seeing. I turned off the cache and loaded the WFS layer, while zoomed to the full extent. The features I received were limited to maxFeature. I then zoomed into a portion of the image that did not have polygons shown. QGIS did not refresh the WFS layer. I then pressed the refresh button but that did not work. No features shown. It appears as though each time I hit refresh Qgis gets a strip of polygons but it's not focusing on the BBox. I'm beggining to suspect that my spatial indexes are messed up.

Comment: Try it another way. As I said, my QGIS does not send new requests if I zoom in so that the new BBOX is totally inside the previous. If you start from full extent your QGIS perhaps believes that you already have all the data. It's not true because maxFeatures was cutting the output but maybe QGIS does not take that into account. Add non-cached layer after you have zoomed into a small BBOX and try if that makes QGIS to send new requests. If is does you will see a small box "Loading GML data".

Comment: BINGO! Refresh works getting new WFS features as I pan through the scene. But If I zoom to full extent, QGIS fill fetch all features and hit the MaxFeatures limit. And then, subsequent zooms do not work since a feature request has already been issued for the entire extent (it believes I have all the data). I believe this is a bug in QGis no? Any idea where to report it?